# How to handle corner cases in 3-sum?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following solution for [3-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM). I use bin search to find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

```
public List<List<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums)
{
    Array.Sort(nums);
    var res = new List<List<int>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < nums.Length; ++j)
        {
            if(nums[i] == nums[j]) { ++i; }

            int c = Array.BinarySearch(nums, -nums[i] - nums[j]);
            if(c > j)
            {
                res.Add(new List<int> { nums[i], nums[j], nums[c] });
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to fix bugs when input is:

`[0,0,0]` or `[0,0,0,0]`

Input:
`[0,0,0]`

Output:
`[]`

Expected:
`[[0,0,0]]`

Comment: .. and those bugs are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

1. Try overloaded version of Array.BinarySearch that takes index of start element and length of elements in the interested range. I.e. you need to find such element in array nums wich located after j-th element only
2. Remove `if(nums[i] == nums[j]) { ++i; }` line. It do almost nothing at corner cases
3. Update `i` and `j` to next non-equal variant of element in corresponding loop.

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       static public List<List<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums)
       {
           Array.Sort(nums);
           var res = new List<List<int>>();
           for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i)
           {
               for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; ++j)
               {
                   int c = Array.BinarySearch(nums, j + 1, nums.Length - j - 1, -nums[i] - nums[j]);

                   if (c > j)
                   {
                       res.Add(new List<int> { nums[i], nums[j], nums[c] });
                   }
                   while (j < nums.Length - 1 && nums[j] == nums[j + 1])
                       j++;
               }
               while (i < nums.Length - 1 && nums[i] == nums[i + 1])
                   i++;
           }

           return res;
       }

       static public void printThreeSum(List<List<int>> list)
       {
           foreach (var item in list)
           {
               foreach (var t in item)
               {
                   Console.Write(t.ToString() + " ");
               }
               Console.Write("\n");
           }
           Console.Write("\n");
       }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { 0, 0, 0 }));
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }));
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }));
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { -1, -1, 2 }));
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2 }));
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { -2, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }));
           printThreeSum(ThreeSum(new int[] { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 }));
       }
   }
   ```

Output:

```
0 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 0

-1 -1 2

-1 -1 2

-2 1 1

-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

P.S. I am not fan of this solution because it is O(N^2 * log(N)) where this task can be solved in O(N^2). I only wanted to correct your code as little as possible

Comment: Sure. Maybe my answer is not clear. In the case `[0,0,0]` `i` will be equal to `0`, `j` will be equal to `1`, but `c` will be equal to `1` in your form, because binary search takes every time middle element and, as result, program fails. You should start binary search  not from the beginning of array, but only in the part where this element is possible. I.e. you should give advice for binary search for your `(c > j )` restriction

Comment: Yes, but how to be with `{0, 0, 0, 0}`? it returns `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` instead of `[0,0,0]`

Comment: I updated my answer. I confused with your {1,1,1,1} example of corner case